# Can credit score be transferred from UK to Australia?

Tags: united-kingdom, australia, banking, financial, credit-history

I have quite a good credit rating in UK which allows me to get mortgages approved more easily, getting credit cards and such,... there is possibility of me ending up in Australia...

I am sure I am not first person to move and I was wondering has anyone successfully 'moved' their credit score to Australia?

**Can credit score be transferred from UK to Australia?**

Comment: Also check on the [Personal Finance](http://money.stackexchange.com) stackexchange, but general consensus from what I've read is no, there's no transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a [foreign citizen in Australia](https://www.homeloanexperts.com.au/non-resident-mortgages/temporary-resident-mortgage/), your credit score on arrival is zero.

For some people (google some forums to see the horror stories) this works out well for them, for others like yourself, it's just one of the many trials of moving countries (I feel your pain).

However, what you can do is get letters of recommendation from your bank, a print of your on-time payments etc, as that may help in any applications for loans in Australia if you can provide evidence of timely payments.